# ¿Como puedo lograr esto?

Tags: javascript, html

Lo que sucede es que cree un sitio donde muestro vídeos o musica, y quiero mostrar información del vídeo o audio en la barra de notificaciones, algo como esto
[image]

Me gustaría lograr mostrar la imagen del vídeo y información del video eso, tal cual lo hace youtube.

Que etiquetas o código javascript se necesita.

En google encontré esto, no se para que sirve:

```
<card type="TYPE_WEBSITE">
<action target="/" title="Title" type="TYPE_EXTERNAL"/>
<placement hide_in_drawer="true" show_in_cta="true"/>
<website_card headline="..." description="description">
<icon image_url="urlImage"/>
</website_card>
</card>
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?, por favor [edit] tu pregunta con mas detalles. También, me da curiosidad saber dónde estás guardado los videos "o de dónde los estás consultando"...

Comment: Intente usar meta etiquetas, e incluso busque por todo google y nada xd

Comment: Los vídeos los guardo en mi server, son vídeos de anime y cosas así. La imagen solo es un ejemplo xd

Comment: AnimationsNow, comprendo, pero, ¿has intentado algo? porque "no estoy 100% seguro", pero no creo que puedas obtener la información del servidor con solo javascript; tienes que hacer algo mas, pero hasta que no edites tu pregunta con mas detalles, me temo que yo no podré ayudarte y es posible que otros usuarios no puedan ayudarte = ayúdanos a ayudarte :)

Comment: Hasta el momento casi nada, solo he buscado en google y usado meta etiquetas que no me dan resultados, solo eso

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta, ahora me podrías decir para que sirve ese código

Comment: ¿Qué términos de búsqueda usaste?, recuerda editar la pregunta, porque los comentarios son temporales.

Comment: Busque algo referente a multimedia tags html y entre todos los resultados apareció ese código, llevos días buscando y no recuerdo de donde lo copee xd

Comment: Ya lo solucione yo mismo xd, lo logre mediante la api de javascript `MediaMetadata`

Comment: @AnimationsNow por favor haz una pregunta que sea útil, ya tienes más de 400 puntos de reputación como para que hagas preguntas incompletas y mal hechas como esa. Debes poner código que tú hayas intentado para lograr tu acometida, no un código aleatorio que ni siquiera sabes que hace. Te daría un +1 si fueras nuevo en StackOverflow como apoyo a que busques la forma de preguntar mejor y con sentido. Pero no eres nuevo. Argumentate bien con lo que quieres, y crea tu codigo de intento. Luego podrás venir a preguntar.

Comment: Ok, solo que no sabia como preguntar, el echo de que tengo x puntos, no me hace un experto o si? :v

Comment: De todas formas perdón por las molestias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias a la api `MediaMetadata` de javascript lo pude solucionar. Aquí dejo la [documentación de la API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaMetadata/MediaMetadata)

```
if ('mediaSession' in navigator){
navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({
title: "Podcast Episode Title",
artist: "Podcast Host",
album: "Podcast Name",
artwork: [{src: "podcast.jpg"}]
});
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('play', function() {});
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('pause', function() {});
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekbackward', function() {});    navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekforward', function() {});
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('previoustrack', function() {});
navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('nexttrack', function() {}); }
```

Comment: `MediaMetadata` no es soportado por casi ningún navegador y no debería ser usado en ningún entorno de producción al ser una tecnología experimental. No les va a funcionar a la mayoría de tus usuarios.

Comment: En chrome funciona perfectamente